# Rails - Simple Form with Nested Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, psql

I am trying to make an app with Rails 4 and Simple Form.

I have three models, being: Project, Scope and Background.

Project has one scope.
Scope has one background.
Scope belongs to project.
Background belongs to scope.
Project accepts nested attributes for Scope.
Scope accepts nested attributes for background.

Project.rb:
      has_one :scope
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :scope

Scope.rb:

```
belongs_to :project
accepts_nested_attributes_for :background
```

Background.rb

```
  belongs_to :scope
```

The scope params are permitted in the project controller. Also, the background attributes are permitted inside the project controller (as scope attributes).

The background params are also permitted in the background controller.

The permitted params in each controller include the relevant _id.

So in the:

- background controller, the permitted params include :scope_id (not :background_id)

  - scope controller, the permitted params include :project_id

This is because these are the foreign keys for those models that belong to another model.

Project controller:

```
def project_params
      params[:project].permit(
      :title, :project_id, scope_attributes: [:background, :project_id, background_attributes: [scope_id, title]])
```

Scope controller:

```
 def scope_params
    params[:scope].permit(:background, project_id, background_attributes: [scope_id, :title])
```

Background controller:

```
params[:background].permit(:scope_id, :title)
```

My trouble is understanding why, when I edit a project in a field that is actually an attribute of background, the db records show the creation of a new id and a new scope_id?

For example, when I originally create a new project, the Background table has ID 1 and scope_id 4.  When I edit this project and go back to look in the Background table of the psql database, the id has become 2 and the scope_id has become 5.

I was expecting these ids to remain as they were orignally because I have only updated the records (not created new ones).

Am I wrong to expect this? Or, have I put the wrong id fields in my permitted params in my controllers? Or, am I wrong to white-label each nested param for background in each of the project, scope and background controller?

Comment: Please post the respective code.

Answer (score 0):

Your `project_params` should look like this

```
def project_params
   params.require(:project).permit(:id,:title, scope_attributes: [:id,:background, :project_id, background_attributes: [:id,scope_id, title]])
end
```

Comment: Hi Pavan, does that mean that I don't need to include ":id" in the params for the scope and background controllers?

Comment: @user2860931 unless your view pages triggered by the actions belongs to respective controllers.

Comment: hmmm - you mean that because the Projects show page includes partials from scope and background, I don't need to include :id in each of the permitted params for the scope and background controllers?

Comment: @user2860931 I can't really tell unless i see your `form code` and respective code from the controllers.

Comment: which part of the controller should i copy over?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are not actually editing the nested objects, but creating a new one each time. So yes, you should include the id in the nested part of the form, and also int he X_attributes section of the require/permit settings in the controller

Comment: Hi Taryn, do you mean each controller? i.e. projects and scope and background?

Comment: What I said was a generalised statement and will apply to all nested objects  - so yes, in every controller

Comment: I'm afraid I'm now confused. Do you mean its a general statement if anything is nested that every id should be in every form and every permitted param in the controller? As in project, has id for project, scope and background; scope has id for project, scope and background and background has id for project, scope and background? Do I need to somehow integrate these id references in my forms for each of these models?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms seems to indicate you shouldn't need it in the forms if you are using "fields_for" http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#the-controller makes it clear that yes, you always need to add `:id` into the controller params-method

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. Unfortunately, I can't understand what you're referring to when you say 'it' and reading the rails guide about adding :id doesn't seem to help me understand what's gone wrong in the settings that I have made. I have read the simple form wiki several times and tried variations on each scenario that I can construe from your answer. I appreciate that you're trying to help, I just don't know what it is that you mean. Thanks anyway.

Comment: "it" is `id` (which is what we have been discussing). according to the guide (as shown in the example in that guide in the section I referenced), you do not need to include id, as long as your form is using `fields_for` are you using `fields_for`?  perhaps you could edit your question and add the view-template that you are using to construct these? (don't reply int he comments with it, code formatting is awful).

Comment: Thank you but I've now found a blog to help guide me. I'm using Simple Form instead of rails forms. If others are reading for this and looking for examples: this cleared things up for me: http://www.createdbypete.com/articles/working-with-nested-forms-and-a-many-to-many-association-in-rails-4/